# Take values after semicolon and duplicate results if there is more than one value, using regex

Tags: php, html, arrays, regex

I have this array `$nodup_filter`:

```
Array(
[0] => <tr><td>29/06/2015</td><td>19:35</td><td>12345 Column information</td><td>67899 Column information - 12</td><td>Rawling Spencer, Peter; Smith Johnson, Katherine</td><td>More information</td></tr>
[1] => <tr><td>12/09/2015</td><td>10:12</td><td>98545 Column information</td><td>67659 Column information - 32</td><td>Cattle Gamme, Mark</td><td>More information</td></tr>
[2] => <tr><td>11/02/2015</td><td>12:40</td><td>59675 Column information</td><td>94859 Column information - 11</td><td>Davis Miller, Patrick; Brown Moore,Stephan; Taylor Jones, Mary</td><td>More information</td></tr>
[3] => <tr><td>01/10/2015</td><td>20:12</td><td>69365 Column information</td><td>78464 Column information - 63</td><td>Willson Chowell, Adrianne; Jackson Bolwin, Stella</td><td>More information</td></tr>
)
```

- If month is > 07, then I expect "1" to be returned after the scriptname, if date is <= 07 then "2" will be returned. **DONE!!**
- From the second column I get the first code and the code after dash "-". If this code is between 50 and 9, then it needs to be transformed, taking the first digit and putting it at units position. Then the tens position might be zero. When is 50 or above, the number ramains as it is. If It's 9 or below, then a zero must be added at tens position. **DONE!**
- Every user is separated by semicolon ";" in the same column. By now I can get the first surname of every user, but I want the first surname from every user in this column. If there is more than one user, then I expect the scriptname to be duplicated for every surname.

Hope it's more clear with the example below.

Here is the expected output:

```
scriptname 2 67899-12 Rawling
scriptname 2 67899-12 Smith

scriptname 1 67659-32 Cattle

scriptname 2 94859-11 Davis
scriptname 2 94859-11 Brown
scriptname 2 94859-11 Taylor

scriptname 1 78464-63 Willson
scriptname 1 78464-63 Jackson
```

And this code with regex to filter it and get the second column information code and the first surname of every element in the array:

```
foreach($nodup_filter as $filtered) {

           /* regex */
            $nodup_filtertoexec = preg_match('/\d{2}\/(\d{2})\/\d{4}.*?\d+\s.*?(\d+)\s.*?-\s(\d+).*?(?:.*?<td>){1}([a-zA-ZñÑ]+).*/m', $filtered, $matches);
           /* regex end */

           /* After dash "-" code management */

            if (isset($matches[3])){
                 if (($matches[3]<50) && ($matches[3]>9)) { 
                      $matches[3] = floor($matches[3]/10);


                      } else if ($matches[3]<10){
              $matches[3] = str_pad($matches[3], "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

                      }

            /* End after dash "-" code management */

            /* Taking 1 or 2 by month number */
            if($matches[1]<=7) {
                         $matches[1]="2";
                    } else{
                         $matches[1]="1";

                }

             /* End Taking 1 or 2 by month number code */

             /* Building final variable */
                 $format = '%d %d-%02d %s';
                 $result = sprintf($format, $matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3], $matches[4]);

             echo 'scriptname '.$result.'<br>';
    /* End building final variable */

            }else{


                  $badresults[] = $filtered;

            }


echo "<br><h2>Rows with some empty information : </h2><br>";
            echo $tableinit;
            foreach($badresults as $bad_results) echo $bad_results;
            echo $tableend;
```

Here is the actual output:

```
scriptname 67899-12 Rawling
scriptname 67659-32 Cattle
scriptname 94859-11 Davis
scriptname 78464-63 Willson
```

Thanks again!!

Comment: @cpilko please, any idea about how to do this with regex? If not, don't worry I'm just want to learn a little. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

No complicated regex needed:

```
foreach($arr as $a){
    $a=str_replace(array('<tr>','</td>'),'',$a); //remove every <tr> and </td>
    $x=explode('<td>',$a); //split in columns

    //MONTH
    //get month part of date, make int and compare
        $month=1;
    if((int)substr($x[1],3,2)<7)$month=2; 

    //CODE
    //just delete some parts of the string in column
    $code=str_replace('Columninformation','',str_replace(' ','',$x[4]));

    //SURNAME
    $n=explode(';',$x[5]);  //split in names
    $names=array();     
    foreach($n as $v){
             //the replace is needed if only 1 surname exists 
        $names[]=str_replace(',','',strtok($v," ")); 
        }

    //loop all found names and create result array
    foreach($names as $n){
        $res[]='scriptname '.$month.' '.$code.' '.$n.'<br>';;
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way: In your specification, what happens if month == 7?

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael! I really appreciate your help. You're right, when month==7 then month =2; 
I'm trying to figure it out with regex because I'm trying to learn a little about it :))
If I can't, your code will be a good way to solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, your name is without a, Michel ;)